# Using the stanford NER to parse product data

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I try to use the Stanford NER to parse product data. My training data looks like the following:

```
iPhone 4 16GB black
Nikon D5100
Apple iPhone 4s
kindle touch
kindle fire
```

Now I want to train the NER with that data, so I have to categorize it first. The standford website provides an example where they parse a chapter of a book and tokenize every word in a new line. This wouldn't help in my case, cause than the data looks like:

```
iPhone
4
16GB
black
```

The "4" should not be in a new line, but when I put "iPhone 4" in a line, the NER thinks that "4" is the category of the token "iPhone".

I just need some help how to train the NER with product data. What would you suggest? And would you categorize "iPhone" as a "phone" and "iPhone 4" also as a "phone"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering wether you'll be able to efficiently extract information using traditional (non-recursive) named entities. In my opinion, you may need something more structured, as:

```
<phone>
    <model> iPhone <model>
    <version> 4 </version>
    <capacity> 16GB <capacity>
    <color> black </color>
</phone>
```

How to recognize structured named entities using CRF is describe for instance in [this paper](http://www.irisa.fr/texmex/people/raymond/pub/icassp2013.pdf). Basically, it learns one CRF per entity type, and combines posterior probabilities (from each individual CRF) to recognize structured named entities.

Indeed, this needs some corpus reengineering, as entities should be have adequate structure un training corpora...